# gitinfo not accessible from unit testcase

Tags: git, scala, maven

I'm writing a scala unittest, 
which checks the git information, and somehow it is not working from the Unit Test

### Added in pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>{git@github.com}/test.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <commitIdGenerationMode>flat</commitIdGenerationMode>
                    <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>true</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                    <failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>true</failOnUnableToExtractRepoInfo>
                    <gitDescribe>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </gitDescribe>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


    folder structures are as shown below :

{project_dir}/module/pom.xml
{project_dir}/module/src/main/scala/BuildInfo.scala 
              (i'm able to read the git info from this file)
 {project_dir}/module_folder/test/main/scala/BuildInfoSuite.scala 
              (i'm NOT able to read the git info from this file)

    Any ideas on what i need to do to get this working ?
```

Some more details :
What changes need to be made in to TestSuite to ensure it read ?
Pls. note - the maven plugin i'm using is - git-commit-id-plugin
Apart from the git values, the other pom.xml parameters eg. build.groupId, build.artifactId, build.version etc are also not available in the Test Suite

Comment: What is the error message?